# Programming certificates

Tags: java, php, sql, certificate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are certifications worth it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44/are-certifications-worth-it)

I'd be glad to hear your opinions on which programming certificates are the most widely recongnized in the industry and how useful are they actually. I've googled a lot this question but I've never asked here and I'd like to gather as many opinions as possible before applying for any. I'm interested mainly in developing business application. I have knowledge in Java, SQL, PHP, some C#. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, programming certifications are not interesting to companies whose product is software.  Those companies are much more interested in general problem-solving ability than in deep knowledge of some specific technology.  They expect developers to be able to learn specific technologies as needed.

Answer (score 0):

None of them.

[Certifications are normally seen as a joke by programmers](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2010/04/27/certification-dont-waste-your-time), and I'd say to avoid companies that require them (as they don't really get software development).

Comment: Since I'm going to have to caveat this, I may as well do it in the comments: Certifications like the Microsoft Certified Master for SQL Server aren't in the same vein as programming certifications.

Comment: I think the point your making is you need to use your brain when assessing whether a programmer with a set of certificates actually knows and understands the theory/technology, and understand what it takes to satisfy the requirements for a certificate. In Microsoft's case this is one of the reasons for their new laddered certification system -- as you progress up through the levels (MCA, MCTS, MCPD, MCTIP, MCM, MCA), you are hopefully becoming more proficient with the technologies.